# jQuery Error - Generating undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have a list of users registered on my site in 1 column, in the 2nd is their email address with a checkbox next to it. On this page a user can check the box (or multiples) and click a submit button. Once they do that it will generate a list of the emails semicolon separated.

My issue is after they hit submit the lists generates, but the first email address has "undefined" written right next to it.. so instead of saying "domain1@test.com; domain2@test.com" it reads "undefindeddomain1@test.com; domain2@test.com".

Here is my jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('#memberSubmit').click(function() {
    var emailList;
    jQuery('.email-members input:checked').each(function() {
        var $this = jQuery(this);
        emailList += $this.next('a').html() + "; ";
    });
    jQuery('.email-message').hide();
    jQuery('.email-members').hide();
    jQuery('.email-checks').hide();
    jQuery('#memberSubmit').hide();
    jQuery('.email-results a').attr('href', "mailto: " + emailList).fadeIn(2000);
    jQuery('.email-results .email-list p').html(emailList).fadeIn(2000);
    jQuery('.email-results h2').fadeIn(2000);
    jQuery('.email-results p').fadeIn(2000);
    jQuery('.email-list h2').fadeIn(2000);
    //console.info('Emails: ' + emailList);
});
});
```

I think my error is on the line: `emailList += $this.next('a').html() + "; ";`
But I am not sure... any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you supply a short HTML example of your setup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initialize the `emailList` the variable first, that means it doesn't start at `undefined` when you perform your first go around. Coincidently, when you're calling `+=` for the first time, it's actually converting `undefined` to a string, thus meaning your string always starting with that.

```
var emailList = "";
```

Comment: Darn it you beat me by a couple of seconds :P

Comment: @Doorknob Hehe I noticed, sorry dude!

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `emailList`'s declaration with this code:

```
var emailList = "";
```

That's because `emailList` starts out as `undefined` if you don't initialize it. Therefore `undefined + "this is a test"` would turn out as `undefinedthis is a test`.

Comment: Mention me in this answer tomorrow and I'll +1 you, I've hit the vote cap for today!